# Calculate this integral $\int \frac{x^2}{4x^4+25}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I have to evaluate the integral

$$\int \frac{x^2}{4x^4+25}\,dx.$$

I thought about parts integration.

Comment: Did you try it with the factorization $4x^4+25=(2x^2-5i)(2x^2+5i)$ and partial fraction decomposition ?

Comment: No way, $x$ is real.

Comment: @Nir This will not affect the result of the integral which is real

Comment: But how do you start ?
Can you show me how to integrate complex number ?

Comment: Let $f :I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Then $\int f(x)dx = \int Re(f(x))dx + i\int Im(f(x))dx$

Comment: @A.Monet they do not teach this method in basic calc as they try to avoid complex numbers. If you can show what you mean in depth in an answer it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$\int  \frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 4x^{ 4 }+25 } dx=\int { \frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 4x^{ 4 }-20{ x }^{ 2 }+25-20{ x }^{ 2 } } dx } =\int { \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ { \left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }-5 \right)  }^{ 2 }-20{ x }^{ 2 } } dx } =\int { \frac { x^{ 2 }dx }{ \left( 2x^{ 2 }-2\sqrt { 5 } x-5 \right) \left( 2x^{ 2 }+2\sqrt { 5 } x-5 \right)  }  }  $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$4x^4+25$ factors as the product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials:
$$4x^4+25=(2x^2+5)^2-20x^2=(2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5)(2x^2+2\sqrt 5x+5,$$
whence the partial fractions decomposition:
$$\frac{x^2}{4x^4+25}=\frac{Ax+B}{2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5}+\frac{Cx+D}{2x^2+2\sqrt 5x+5}.$$
As $\dfrac{x^2}{4x^4+25}$ is an even function, we have $C=-A,\enspace B=D$. Setting $x=0$ shows $B=D=0$, and reducing to the same denominator yields $A=\dfrac{\sqrt 5}{20}$. Hence we have to compute:
$$\frac{\sqrt5}{20}\int\frac{ x}{2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5}\,\mathrm d x-\frac{\sqrt5}{20}\int\frac{x}{2x^2+2\sqrt 5x+5}\,\mathrm d x$$
Now split each integral:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{ x}{2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5}\,\mathrm d x&= \frac14\int\frac{4x-2\sqrt5}{2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5}\,\mathrm d x+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{4x^2-4\sqrt 5x+10} \\[1ex]
&=\frac14\ln(2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5)+\frac14\int\frac{\mathrm d(2x-\sqrt5)}{(2x-\sqrt5)^2+5} \\[1ex]
&= \frac14\ln(2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5)+\frac1{4\sqrt5}\,\arctan(2x-\sqrt5)
\end{align*}
Similarly,
$$\int\frac{ x}{2x^2+2\sqrt 5x+5}\,\mathrm d x=\frac14\ln(2x^2+2\sqrt 5x+5)+\frac1{4\sqrt5}\,\arctan(2x+\sqrt5)$$
Thus we obtain
$$\int\frac{x^2}{4x^4+25}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt5}{80}\ln\biggl(\frac{2x^2-2\sqrt 5x+5}{2x^2+2\sqrt 5x+5}\biggr)+\frac{\sqrt5}{400}(\arctan(2x-\sqrt5)-\arctan(2x+\sqrt5)). $$

The last term may be further simplified using the formula $\;\arctan p-\arctan q \equiv\arctan\dfrac{p-q}{1+pq}\mod\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Apply the factorization
$$a^4 + b^4 = (a^2- \sqrt{2} a b + b^2) (a^2 + \sqrt{2} a b + b^2)$$
to the denominator and apply the Method of Partial Fractions to decompose the integrand.

Comment: Here you have a good answer

Comment: How do you use that ? I dont understand.

Comment: Do you know how to decompose this term ?
$$\frac { 1 }{ \left( 2x^{ 2 }-2\sqrt { 5 } x-5 \right) \left( 2x^{ 2 }+2\sqrt { 5 } x-5 \right)  }$$

Comment: @NirMovshovitz We can write the denominator in the integrand as $(\sqrt{2} x)^4 + (\sqrt{5})^4$, so we can factor the denominator as a product of quadratic polynomials by setting $a = \sqrt{2} x$ and $b = \sqrt{5}$ and substituting in the above formula. Then, we'll have entirely factored the denominator of the rational expression into a product of irreducible quadratic polynomials, which means we are prepared to apply the Method of Partial Fractions and then proceed with integrating as usual.

Comment: Yes.
But somehow there are problems for me with this equation.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is your difficult writing out the factorization, or applying partial fractions?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{x^2}{4x^4+25}dx\\=&\int \frac{1}{4x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}}dx
= \frac14\int \frac{2+\frac5{x^2}}{4x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}}
 + \frac{2-\frac5{x^2}}{4x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac14\int \frac{d(2x-\frac5{x})}{(2x-\frac5{x})^2+20}
 + \frac{d(2x+\frac5{x})}{(2x+\frac5{x})^2-20}\\
=&\ \frac1{8\sqrt5}\bigg(\tan^{-1}\frac{2x^2-5}{2\sqrt5x} -\coth^{-1}\frac{2x^2+5}{2\sqrt5x}\bigg)+C
\end{align}